# Next.js Link Tag does not scroll the page on top

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am using the overflow tailwind class in my div which is supposedly causing this issue.
The class which I am using is

```
// the scrollable navbar component in the left side of the web page
    <div className="overflow-y-auto mb-20 pb-4">
      <div className="max-w-[15rem] text-neutral-300 pl-4">
        {o.items?.map((data) => (
          <Link href={`/data/${data.id}`} key={data.id} scroll={true}>
            <p
              className="leading-loose text-sm font-semibold truncate ..."
              key={data.id}
            >
              {data.name}
            </p>
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>


//this data changes when item id is changed from the navbar but it does not scroll to top.
<div className="h-screen flex flex-col bg-neutral-900">
  <div className="grow max-w-7xl m-4 mb-20 pb-4 overflow-y-scroll">
    {data}
  </div>
</div>
```

If this class is removed, the page is updated and the scroll works properly.
I need assistance in solving this question, some help is appreciated

Comment: can u share a snippet or something, so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I have done some edits, please check if you understand the issue now.

Comment: if u dont spend a minimum of time creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), u think someone will spend some time trying to figure out what is the problem here and then solve it?